# Semicolon usage in a sentence

Tags: semicolons

Is it correct to use a semicolon or a comma in this sentence?

> I worked on quite a few projects and websites since 2009; some of them are shown in the portfolio above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I absolutely think it is. The rule of thumb for semi-colon use is when you have two stand-alone clauses (i.e. where you have a full stop at the end), and want to connect them.

Semi-colons shouldn't be used with conjunctions (and/or/but etc), but your sentence doesn't have this feature.

You would also be fine to use 2 clauses, but particularly for readability, the semi-colon helps the reader understand there is a connection between the two clauses.

[The Oatmeal](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon) has some quite lovely tips which you may find helpful, amusing and interesting.

Comment: I disagree about the use of conjunctions with semicolons; but there is room for difference between mechanical and rhetorical pointers; and perhaps we will reach a punctuated equilibrium.

Answer (score -2):

Using semicolon is art, if you use in wrong part in sentence then it going to make sentence grammatically mistake.

Semi colon is used to distinguish the sentence from the paragraph.

Example
I went to shopping and bought; Watches, bags, dresses.

So it defines
I went to shopping and bought watches.
I went to shopping and bought bags.

The word start often the semicolon should always start with capital letter.

Reference

[A dot and colon: Semi colon](https://balabb.com/learn/english/grammar/a-dot-and-colon-semicolon-usage)

Comment: Oh good gracious, no. This is wrong. There should be no 'to' after 'went', no capital 'W' for 'watches' and the last element of the list should have 'and' and not a comma. : "I went shopping and bought watches, bags and dresses.". Or with a semi-colon "I went shopping; I bought watches, bags and dresses."

Comment: Oops, I take your comments seriously. Hope It's my mistake. Not proof read the sentence. Mr Steve Ives. sentence or word that starts after semi colon should be in capital.

Comment: No - the word after the semi-colon is still part of the sentence, so should only be capitalised as per normal rules for proper nouns, cities, countries, 'I' etc.

Comment: Yup, you are absolutely right. I made a complete reference and finally got it.  I found some examples                                                                                                                     "The woman was heartbreakingly beautiful; she was dark and stormy; she was utterly dangerous." Thanks for alerting me Mr.Steve